# Angular - Disable next button when at end of array

Tags: angular, button

I'm trying to have my previous button be disabled whenever you're at the beginning of an array and my next button be disabled whenever you've reached the end of the array. The user will select an employee from a combo box which will get the index of the selected employee into a variable named selectedEmployee. I have gotten the previous button to work but not the next button for some reason.

Here's my tracker.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PTODataService } from './pto-data.service';
import { PTOData } from './pto-data';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-tracker',
    templateUrl: `./tracker.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./tracker.component.css']
})

export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit{
    empInfo: EmpInfo[];
    ptoData: PTOData[];
    isHidden: boolean = false;

    public selectedEmployee: number = 0;
    public selectedType: string = "PTO";

    constructor(
        private empInfoService: EmpInfoService,
        private ptoDataService: PTODataService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => this.empInfo = empInfo
            );
    }

    getPTOData(): void {
        this.ptoDataService.getPTODatas().then(
            ptoData => this.ptoData = ptoData
        );
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
        this.getPTOData();
    }

    toggleSummary(): void {
        this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    }

    nextEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee+1;
    }

    previousEmployee(): void {
        this.selectedEmployee = this.selectedEmployee-1;
    }

    isPreviousValid() {
        if (this.selectedEmployee > 0) {
            return true;
        }   
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    isNextValid() {
        if (this.selectedEmployee < EmpInfo.length) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and here's a snippet of my html where i'm trying to implement it:

```html
    <button [disabled]="isNextValid()"class="form-control" style="width: 150px;" (click)="nextEmployee()">Next</button>
    <button [disabled]="!isPreviousValid()" class="form-control" style="width: 150px;" (click)="previousEmployee()">Previous</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use variable name **empInfo** instead of class name. Please check below code

```
isNextValid() {
    if (this.selectedEmployee < this.empInfo.length) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm getting an error that says "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: At which line you are getting the error? I am pretty sure it's in getEmpInfo() function, but i want to confirm. Have you tried my code?

Comment: I put in your code and it runs, but in the browser, the app breaks and i get that error

Comment: can you see in the browser's console the line at which you are getting error?

Comment: it just says ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at TrackerComponent.isNextValid (:50/app/tracker.component.js:52)

Comment: Just initialize your array element empInfo: EmpInfo[] = new Array<EmpInfo>() in the constructor to get away with the error. It will be helpful for me to find the exact issue if you share your code via plunker.

Comment: Okay, I did that. But, now my next button is always disabled? and I have 10+ pages in my app that are all connected so it'd take a while to make the plunker

Comment: @rcarc as you wish. I am sure there is something trivial which you are missing.

Comment: I figured it out, I just had to do a hard refresh and it worked. Thanks!